# dc.js - part of line chart not visible

Tags: linechart, dc.js

I am trying to render a line chart with given data. It is displaying with some part of line graph missing. The code is as below,

`function lineChart(){
        var pu = [{"power_used":74.77,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T18:00:00","date":"2015-12-18T18:00:00.000Z","snr":74.77},{"power_used":74.68,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T18:05:00","date":"2015-12-18T18:05:00.000Z","snr":74.68},{"power_used":74.52,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T18:10:00","date":"2015-12-18T18:10:00.000Z","snr":74.52},{"power_used":74.69,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T18:15:00","date":"2015-12-18T18:15:00.000Z","snr":74.69},{"power_used":74.7,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T18:20:00","date":"2015-12-18T18:20:00.000Z","snr":74.7},{"power_used":74.66,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T18:25:00","date":"2015-12-18T18:25:00.000Z","snr":74.66},{"power_used":72.78,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T18:30:00","date":"2015-12-18T18:30:00.000Z","snr":72.78},{"power_used":46.56,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T18:35:00","date":"2015-12-18T18:35:00.000Z","snr":46.56},{"power_used":74.77,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T18:40:00","date":"2015-12-18T18:40:00.000Z","snr":74.77},{"power_used":59.22,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T18:45:00","date":"2015-12-18T18:45:00.000Z","snr":59.22},{"power_used":30.14,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T18:50:00","date":"2015-12-18T18:50:00.000Z","snr":30.14},{"power_used":30.24,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T18:55:00","date":"2015-12-18T18:55:00.000Z","snr":30.24},{"power_used":41.83,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T19:00:00","date":"2015-12-18T19:00:00.000Z","snr":41.83},{"power_used":74.92,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T19:05:00","date":"2015-12-18T19:05:00.000Z","snr":74.92},{"power_used":74.64,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T19:10:00","date":"2015-12-18T19:10:00.000Z","snr":74.64},{"power_used":74.74,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T19:15:00","date":"2015-12-18T19:15:00.000Z","snr":74.74},{"power_used":74.75,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T19:20:00","date":"2015-12-18T19:20:00.000Z","snr":74.75},{"power_used":74.66,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T19:25:00","date":"2015-12-18T19:25:00.000Z","snr":74.66},{"power_used":41.06,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T19:30:00","date":"2015-12-18T19:30:00.000Z","snr":41.06},{"power_used":30.36,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T19:35:00","date":"2015-12-18T19:35:00.000Z","snr":30.36},{"power_used":30.28,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T19:40:00","date":"2015-12-18T19:40:00.000Z","snr":30.28},{"power_used":30.22,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T19:45:00","date":"2015-12-18T19:45:00.000Z","snr":30.22},{"power_used":30.24,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T19:50:00","date":"2015-12-18T19:50:00.000Z","snr":30.24},{"power_used":30.22,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T19:55:00","date":"2015-12-18T19:55:00.000Z","snr":30.22},{"power_used":30.2,"capture_at":"2015-12-18T20:00:00","date":"2015-12-18T20:00:00.000Z","snr":30.2}];
        var data = pu;
        console.log("Actual data"+JSON.stringify(data));
        var snr = "power_used";
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
        var dateRange = [];
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            var newdat = new Date(d.capture_at);
            //console.log("Date value::::  "+parseDate(newdat));
            var datee=parseDate(newdat);
                d.date = new Date(datee);
            dateRange.push(d.date);
                d.snr = d[snr];
            console.log("For each " + snr + " " + d[snr]);
        });
        console.log("snr = " + snr);
        var cf = crossfilter(data);
        var dimByTime = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.date;});
        var groupForSNR = dimByTime.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d[snr]; });
        var minDate = dimByTime.bottom(1)[0].date;
        var maxDate = dimByTime.top(1)[0].date;
        var chart = dc.lineChart("#power_used");
        chart
          .width(450).height(140)
          .dimension(dimByTime)
          .group(groupForSNR)
          .renderDataPoints(true)
          .brushOn(false)
          .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
          //.y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,200]).range([0,groupForSNR.all()[0].value]))
          .xAxis().ticks(12);
        chart.on("renderlet", function (chart) {
                chart.selectAll("g.x text")
                  .attr('dx', '+18')
                  .attr('transform', "rotate(+30)");
        })
        chart.render();
      }`

"power_used" is the id of html div element which will hold this line chart.
 
[image: image of clipped line chart]

The part of line chart looks to be hiding behind the ~50th tick mark on y-axis. I am able to see the all data points on line graph on dev tools including those which are hidden on screen.
   If anybody has a solution for this it would be a great help.

Comment: Thanks for providing complete code, this makes it easy to test. Even better to put it in a fiddle because that will help isolate the problem. When I did this, [the chart shows fine](http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/febhzdLk/2/). Could there be something else in your page that is interfering?

Comment: @Gordon, I found there was a clip-path attribute which was pointing to a rectangle not covering the entire line graph. So, that is why the issue occurred. The answer for, why clip-path was generated on my specific project is yet to be investigated. As of now I have solved this issue with work around.  $('.chart-body').attr("clip-path",""); Please let me know if there is anything I need to take care of.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the rest of your code. The code you posted above seems to work okay. Is there some resizing going on? The dc.js code is not perfect in that area.

Comment: There is always a clip-path on line and bar charts because they might be zoomed in. Don't yet know why it would be incorrect for your chart.